# Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring, android-volley, apache-commons-fileupload

I keep getting MalformedStreamException
I am Running tomcat 9 with Java 8
Client is sending multipart file upload (picture and picture name)
Here is the function signature:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
 @RequestMapping(value = "/fileupload", headers=("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload( 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("pictureId") String pictureId
```

This is the multipartResolver configuration in Spring dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<!-- max upload size in bytes -->
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

<!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
<property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->
```

Code that submit the multipart is using android volley:

```
       SimpleMultiPartRequest multiPartRequest = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Contents.API_SUBMIT_PICTURE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("logEntry", "API_SUBMIT_PICTURE: " + response);
                    }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("logEntry", "API_SUBMIT_PICTURE: onErrorResponse");
                    submission.failedCount ++;
                    submission.errorDetail = "API_SUBMIT_PICTURE: onErrorResponse";
                }
            }
        );

        multiPartRequest.addFile("file", submissionFile.fileLocation);
        multiPartRequest.addStringParam("pictureId", submissionFile.pictureId);

        volleyHelper.add(multiPartRequest);
```

Here is what I tried so far:
I upgraded commons file upload to 1.3.3
Upgraded java to 1.8
Upgraded tomcat to 9
Some posts suggested setting maxSowllowSize in tomcat - so I set it to -1 didn't help...
network connection is fine (tested both on wifi and internet with small files)
Code that submit the

Full Stack trace:

```
May 08, 2018 9:58:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/xerox_v6] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly] with root cause
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:906)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.filters.LoginInterceptor.doFilter(LoginInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.xerox.infrastructure.filters.LoginInterceptor.doFilter(LoginInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:906)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: no, im still getting it from time to time :(

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: still a mystery...

Comment: I have added an answer which helped me, I hope it helps you and others with a similar issue.

Comment: Did you try the Tomcat / Spring Boot upgrade?

Comment: Not yet, I am going to try.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where some bigger requests or file uploads resulted in "Stream ended unexpectedly" error.

Turns out it was due to Tomcat 9.0.31 and upgrading it fixed the issue. [This article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-we-found-apache-tomcat-couldnt-handle-large-requests-fd41b8b5f8e7) explains it in more detail.

EDIT: If you are using a Spring or Spring Boot version which uses Tomcat 9.0.31, try to upgrade to a version which uses a newer Tomcat version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after so much search I was able to fix it with the following code.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileNameWithPath))) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("$")) {
      list.add(builder.toString());
      builder.setLength(0);
    } else {
      builder.append(line).append("\r\n");
    }
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Well the issue is because of how it reads the escape sequence "\n" in different spring boot versions. I fixed it by replacing "\n" with "\r\n"

Answer (score -7):

This exception looks like your file transfer process has been interrupted unexpected.

Please check your network connection,and you should catch this exception in your code,clean up file upload state,and re-upload file.

As usual,you should learn how to implement "http file transfer resuming".Of course,this will increase your code complexity :)